# CosmosDB SQL API: Change property Name - (Partial Updates .Net SDK or loops)

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi, .net-6.0

Consider the following data
[image: Data]

I am trying to update the property name from givenName to PetName. Below are the things I tried.

**Option 1:**

```
List<PatchOperation> patchOperations = new List<PatchOperation>();

dynamic data = new
{
    PetName= "Dummy"
};

//Remove the 0th element from the pet array 
patchOperations.Add(PatchOperation.Remove("/children/0/pets/0"));
//insert the new entity
patchOperations.Add(PatchOperation.Add<dynamic>("/children/0/pets/0", data));

await Container.PatchItemAsync<dynamic>("AndersenFamily", new 
PartitionKey("AndersenFamily"), patchOperations);
```

This works on the first element (as I have specified the index as 0).
[image]

But I couldn't find a way to update all the elements in the array. Something like **/children/*/pets** (I get an error "Invalid navigation for array(*)").

**Option 2:**

Read all the data from the database, remove the existing pets and upload the new object with the property PetName. But I guess it will take lot of time to loop through all the objects and make these changes.

Can someone suggest a better solution or a way to fix the partial updates so that it updates all the elements in the array?

The actual dataset that I am working on is huge and has more nested arrays.

Comment: Hi Anish, I am from the Cosmos DB PM team, can you provide the subscrition and your cosmos account name?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are right, Current version of Patch does not support patching nested  array. You need to know the **`index`** in order to replace/add values as you mentioned in the first question.

One way to think about this would be to write your own logic to replace the keys , there are libraries available in dotnet and then using the bulk insert using the SDK to insert those documents.